# Residue of $\frac{z^5}{(z-i)^3}$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

Find residue of $\frac{z^5}{(z-i)^3}$ at $z=i$

I am having trouble solving this. This is what I have done so far:

$f(z)$ is in the form $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ so $\operatorname{Res}(f,i)= \frac{p(i)}{q'(i)}$.

$q(z) = (z-i)^3=z^3-3iz^2+3i^2z-i^3=z^3-3iz^2-3z+i$

$\operatorname{Res}(f,i)= \frac{p(i)}{q'(i)}=\frac{(i)^5}{3z^2-6i-3}=\frac{(i)^5}{3i^2-6i-3}=\frac{(i)^5}{-3-6i-3}=\frac{(i)^5}{-9-6i}$.

I get $\operatorname{Res}(f,i)=\frac{(i)^5}{-9-6i}$ but the correct answer is $-10i$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there even a residue? I can't see that the function has a pole at $z=i$.

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is you didn't state the question correctly! That function is analytic at $z=i$, so the residue is $0$.

Comment: I feel as if he copied the wrong problem.

Comment: IF it was supposed to be $(z-i)^3$: (i) you shouldn't make us guess! (ii) that formula $p(z)/q'(z)$ gives the residue of $p/q$ _if_ $q$ has a _simple_ zero.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It should be $(z-i)^3$

Comment: Presuming it to be $(z-i)^3$ in the denominator, it is a pole of order 3 and the residue is given by $\dfrac 1{2!}(z^5)''(i)=10i^3=-10i$

Comment: I just like to add that you have a mistake in your computation. The derivative of the denominator is $3z^2-6iz-3$ and at $z=i$ it become $0$. That is not surprising, since $\frac{d}{dz}(z-i)^3=3(z-i)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a particular method for finding a residue of a pole is we rewrite our function $f(z)$ as
$$f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n},$$
where $z_0$ is the pole and $n$ is the order. Then
$$\text{Res}(f, z_0)=\frac{\phi^{(n-1)}(z_0)}{(n-1)!}.$$

So, we identify that $\phi(z)=z^5$, $z_0=i$ and $n=3$. Then
$$\phi''(z)=20z^3,$$
so $$\phi''(i)=-20i,$$
thus
$$\text{Res}(f, i)=\frac{-20i}{2}=-10i.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since\begin{align}z^5&=\bigl(i+(z-i)\bigr)^5\\&=i+5 (z-i)-10 i (z-i)^2-10 (z-i)^3+5 i (z-i)^4+(z-i)^5,\end{align}you know that$$\frac{z^5}{(z-i)^3}=\frac i{(z-i)^3}+\frac5{(z-i)^2}-\frac{10 i}{z-i}-10+5 i (z-i)+(z-i)^2$$and therefore the residue at $i$ is $-10i$.

Answer (score 0):

That formula $p/q'$ is only valid if $q$ has a simple zero.

By definition the residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-i)$ in the Laurent expansion. You can find the expansion by writing $$z^5=((z-i)+i)^5=(z-i)^5+5i(z-i)^4+\dots.$$